# base64 pdf is not showing in IE 11 browser

Tags: angularjs

As same base64 pdf is showing on chrome and mozilla firefox but it is not showing in IE browser please let me now the solution for it my code is as below

var pdf=response.data?response.data.base64:"";

```
            var doc = document.createElement("a");
            doc.href ='data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + pdf;
            doc.target = "blank";
            //    doc.download = response.data.fileName?response.data.fileName:"";
            if(response.data.base64){                    //$window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdf);
            var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64,"  + response.data.base64 + "'></iframe>" 
            //var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + response.data.base64 + "'></iframe>"
            var x = window.open();
            x.document.open();
            x.document.write(iframe);
            x.document.title = 'IndiaFIRST';
            x.document.close();
            }
```

Comment: so whats is the solution for it can you please let me no.-Marcus Hoglund

Comment: As the accepted answer display, read the bytes to a blob and then window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);